# Buttons moving when different resolution on monitor

Tags: html, css, button, screen, resolution

Hello so today i was making new layout for my website and i was adding buttons to header but this happens (here is screenshot from my 1st screen 1920x1080, buttons will show normally)  [image]

And my 2nd screen (1360x768)

[image]

```
#header {
background:#CCC;
width:100%;
height:58px;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
display:inline-block;}


.buttons {
margin-left:800px;
    position:relative;
```

}

```
#button a {
font-family:Trebuchet MS;
text-decoration:none;
color:#fff;
font-size:30px;
display:inline-block;
padding:8px 10px;
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
```

}

Comment: you should include some html in the question but without it, I'd have to guess the problem is your margin-left:800px;

Comment: <div id="header">
<img style="float:left;" src="images/logo.png" width="400" height="58">
<div id="button">
<div class="buttons">

Comment: try adding a float right to #button and remove the margin-left

Comment: `margin-left: 800px` is causing most of the problem, but you're gonna need to use percentages and other responsive units if you aren't going to use media-queries.

Comment: Yea it worked but now it go like this: [CLICK](https://gyazo.com/6328c2f7228882e6e1ba132a0f720177)

Comment: Now i only need get that zoom thing work, any ideas?

Comment: It looks like your logo image is too large then. Try changing that width to a percentage. And make sure float right is on #button NOT #button a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change font-size for different resolutions with media queries.
Example:

```
@media (min-width: 1300px) and (max-width: 1600px) {
#button a {
font-size: 20px;
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are virtually saying: Use up all space necessary and leave 800px margin on the left side. Once the screen size is small enough so your text + 800px margin wont fit, it will drop to another line.

```
    .buttons {
      margin-left:800px;
      position:relative;
     }
```

Make the div as wide as you need and float it on the right side. If your div goes under the limit you establish, it will again drop on another line because it does not have enough space to be on one line. Hence is the rule of text-formatting.

```
    .buttons {
     width: 800px; // change so your buttons are on one line
     margin-right: 25px;
     float: right; 
     }
```

You can then modify the behaviour by using @media rules if you want it to fit on a even smaller screen.

```
     @media screen and (max-width: 768px){
     .buttons {font-size: 0.8em;}
     }
```